# Bucle for anidado y concatenar array

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente bucle:

```
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];

for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
console.log(j);
}
}
```

...Y necesito concatenarle a cada resultado el miArray3:

```
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];
```

debería imprimir:

```
10 TaT, 11 TaT, 12 TaT, 13 TaT, 14 TaT, 15 TaT, 20 Pan, 21 Pan, 22 Pan.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes de concatenar y listo:

```js
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];

for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
console.log(j + miArray3[i]);
}
}
```